# .NET 6.0 Task.Delay блокирует поток навсегда

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

```
    static async Task Foo() {
        while (true) {
            await Task.Delay(1000);
            Console.WriteLine("PRINT");
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var strip = new MenuStrip();
        Foo();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Данный пример кода демонстрирует странное поведение: после создания экземпляра `MenuStrip` метод `Foo` блокируется на моменте вызова `Task.Delay`. Если не создавать экземпляр `MenuStrip`, всё работает как должно - каждую секунду на консоль выводится сообщение `PRINT`. Почему так происходит?

Target Framework: .NET 6.0

Target OS: Windows

Проект: https://cloud.mail.ru/public/kj7m/PQt2DfzXk

Comment: Откуда MenuStrip? WinForms? / Компоненты WinForms должны запускаться в потоке STA (Single Threaded Apartment). Между тем, по умолчанию потоки создаются MTA (Multi Threaded Apartment). Думаю, дело в этом.

Comment: _"WinForms?"_ - Да. Почему же тогда например с `NotifyIcon` такого не происходит?

Comment: _"Компоненты WinForms должны запускаться в потоке STA"_ - Всё же не совсем понимаю как это влияет на async-методы. Если запустить код с выводом сообщения на консоль в отдельном потоке с использованием `ThreadPool`, то всё работает в любом случае нормально.

Comment: Поставьте атрибут `[STAThread]` над `Main`. Долгая история про COM и Message Loop. `Delay` тут вообще не при чем, он освобождает поток, а возврат не происходит, потому что UI компонент вешает процесс. При чем после ожидания, возврат произойдет в поток из пула, и вы снова не сможете работать с UI компонентами. Нужен однопоточный контекст синхронизации. Создайте просто Winforms приложение и не мучайтесь, там всё устроено как надо.

Comment: Так может сделать нормально - `async Main` и `await Foo`? Ну и может `ConfigureAwait(false)` ещё нужен будет.

Comment: @CrazyElf в консольном приложении нет контекста синхронизации, `ConfigureAwait` бесполезен, так как он предназначен для выхода из этого самого контекста.

Comment: _"Поставьте атрибут [STAThread] над Main."_ - Ситуация не меняется. _"Создайте просто Winforms приложение и не мучайтесь, там всё устроено как надо."_ - Я работаю над серверным приложением и WinForms мне совсем не нужен, я просто сильно упростил код, чтобы более наглядно продемонстрировать проблему с которой я столкнулся. _"Так может сделать нормально - async Main и await Foo?"_ - Мне нужно запустить метод `Foo` несколько раз асинхронно и продолжить работу метода `Main` дальше, не дожидаясь когда `Foo` завершится. Пример кода, который я привёл, опять же, упрощён.

Comment: Ну тогда Task.Run

Comment: @CrazyElf А разве есть разница? У меня там стоит другая конструкция: `Foo().ContinueWith(...)`

Comment: _Я работаю над серверным приложением и WinForms мне совсем не нужен_ - `new MenuStrip()` а это тогда что? Это Winforms. _У меня там стоит другая конструкция_ - при наличии `async/await` такие конструкции не рекомендуется использования, они запутывают код.

Comment: _"new MenuStrip() а это тогда что? Это Winforms"_ - Да, это нужно для отображения иконки в трее. Разве имеет смысл ради этого изменять тип проекта на WinForms? Мне проще вообще не использовать WinForms, если это было бы так критично. _"при наличии async/await такие конструкции не рекомендуется использования, они запутывают код."_ - Может быть и так, но как по другому сделать, если мне нужно запустить метод `Foo` в нескольких потоках сразу? И всё же мы отходим от темы вопроса... Добавление атрибута `[STAThread]` ничего не поменяло.

Comment: Кроме того, вы пишите: _"`Delay` тут вообще не при чем, он освобождает поток, а возврат не происходит, потому что UI компонент вешает процесс."_ - почему же такого не происходит с `NotifyIcon`? Лишь некоторые компоненты вызывают такое поведение, а не все.

Comment: `NotifyIcon` не работает в потоке приложения. Он хостится в трее.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MenuStrip`, являясь компонентом Windows Forms, автоматически устанавливает контекст синхронизации Windows Forms в своём конструкторе.

Избежать этого можно задав свойству [`WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext.AutoInstall`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.windowsformssynchronizationcontext.autoinstall) значение false:

```cs
    WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext.AutoInstall = false;
    var strip = new MenuStrip();
    Foo();
    Console.ReadKey();
```

Однако, как правило компонентам этот контекст зачем-то нужен, так что в общем случае просто ставить false нежелательно. Вместо этого можно явно вынести вызов метода Foo из контекста синхронизации:

```cs
    var strip = new MenuStrip();
    Task.Run(() => Foo());
    Console.ReadKey();
```

Также, если уж вы создаёте какие-то контролы Windows Forms - скорее всего, вам понадобится главный цикл. Его запуск также устранит проблему:

```cs
    var strip = new MenuStrip();
    Foo();
    Application.Run();
```

Если вам при этом нужно закрытие приложения при нажатии клавиши в консоли - читать придётся в другом потоке, а закрывать - через контекст приложения:

```cs
    var strip = new MenuStrip();
    Foo();
    
    var context = new ApplicationContext();
    Task.Run(() => {
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit");
        Console.ReadKey();
        context.ExitThread(); // хотя название тут ExitThread, на самом деле это выход из Application.Run
    });
    Application.Run(context);
```

Comment: Разве `Task.Run(() => Foo());` выносит из контекста синхронизации?

Comment: @vitidev да. Задачи, запущенные через Task.Run, исполняются в пустом контексте синхронизации планировщиком по умолчанию.

Comment: Можно объяснить эту ситуацию на уровне потоков? То есть конструктор `MenuStrip` устанавливает контекст синхронизации на основной поток, далее создаётся ещё один поток для метода `Foo`, но после того await Task будет завершён, контекст переключится на исходный и дальнейшее выполнение будет идти в первом потоке, но тот заблокирован ожиданием ввода с консоли.

Comment: Почему же `Application.Run` решает проблему?

Comment: Не совсем понимаю эту историю с контекстом синхронизации. То есть второму потоку назначается тот же контекст синхронизации, что установлен для первого, а после await Task весь хвост метода отправляется на выполнение первому потоку, второй при этом уничтожается.

Comment: @D.Stark вы сейчас про какой из вариантов спрашиваете? В том где делается `Application.Run()`, никакого второго потока не создаётся. В том, где делается `Application.Run(context)`, второй поток занят исключительно чтением с клавиатуры.

Comment: Application.Run решает проблему потому что запускает цикл обработки сообщений, который обрабатывает так же и продолжения задач

Comment: @D.Stark а, код из вашего вопроса тоже не создаёт никакого второго потока

Comment: @PavelMayorov А как же асинхронный вызов? А если уберем `new MenuStrip`?

Answer (score 2):

Вот так код работает:

```
static async Task Foo()
{
    while (true)
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000).ConfigureAwait(false);
        Console.WriteLine("PRINT");
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var strip = new MenuStrip();
    Foo();
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Добавлен `.ConfigureAwait(false)`.

Обычное консольное приложение не имеет контекста синхронизации, но данная программа по факту является приложением WinForms, поэтому в ней есть контекст синхронизации. Соответственно, нужно учитывать его наличие.

Атрибут `[STAThread]`, скорее всего, понадобится только в случае использование COM-объектов или компонентов, использующих их внутри себя.

Компонент `NotifyIcon`, хостится не на форме, а в трее и, насколько я понимаю, не использует поток сообщений формы напрямую. Поэтому его поведение отличается от стандартных оконных контролов.